# How to execute mysqldump command in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, command, dump, execute

First of all I go to mysql workbench directory using the command prompt(cmd.exe), then  I have the fallowing command that works correctly:

```
mysqldump --host=ip1 --user=username --password=123 --dadabase=dbName --tables tb1 --quick --force --routines --events --lock-tables=false ==compress | mysql --host=ip2 --user=username --password=123 -b dbName
```

My problem is when I try to execute this command in application the code is:

```
Process.Start("C:\program files\Mysql\Mysql Workbench 6.3 CE\mysqldump.exe","--host=ip1 --user=username --password=123 --dadabase=dbName --tables tb1 --quick --force --routines --events --lock-tables=false ==compress | mysql --host=ip2 --user=username --password=123 -b dbName")
```

When I execute this code, nothing happens... I also try to use shell

```
dim id as integer = Shell("C:\program files\Mysql\Mysql Workbench 6.3 CE\mysqldump.exe --host=ip1 --user=username --password=123 --dadabase=dbName --tables tb1 --quick --force --routines --events --lock-tables=false ==compress | mysql --host=ip2 --user=username --password=123 -b dbName")
```

certainly I'm usin the parameters in wrong way :( ... Can someone help me?
I also used federated table but in this situation because of big size of the table, the ram of the servers was overcharged....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution, that is:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/k cd C:\Program Files MySQL Server 5.7\bin\ & mysqldump --host=ip1 --user=username --password=123 --dadabase=dbName --tables tb1 --quick --force --routines --events --lock-tables=false ==compress | mysql --host=ip2 --user=username --password=123 -b dbName & exit")
```

before I was trying to execute mysqldump directly, but i realized that I had to execute the command prompt(cmd.exe) first and execute mysqldump  in it own dir using the parameters that i need. (when we use /k in the begining of the arguments we can use multiple commands and the char '&' separates different commands such as change directory or execute the mysqldump.exe).

Answer (score 0):

```
Shell("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --user=root --password=admin --host=localhost --databases myDB > C:/db_backup.sql")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work to me, because I will have to create another process that restore the backup file, and because some specific reasons I have to move the data directly from a server to the storage. Also this command didn´t work when a run it in VB.net, only work when I´m using the command prompt.